# CURLOPT_POSTFIELD value not recognized

Tags: c++, string, curl

> Thanks to @Mat 's comment i got the solution:
>
> I replaced
>
> `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cQuery);`
>
> with
>
> `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(cQuery));`
>
> `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, cQuery);`

i am currently struggling at a more or less strange problem which drives me nuts.

I am using the following code to create the value i want to use for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to perform a CURL request.

```
string query;
map<string, string> parameters = resource->GetParameters();
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it_type;
int i = 0;
for (it_type iterator = parameters.begin(); iterator != parameters.end(); iterator++, i++) {
    if (i > 0)
        query.append("&");
    query = query.append(iterator->first).append("=").append(iterator->second);
}
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
const char *cQuery = query.c_str();
cout << cQuery << endl;
cout << "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=default" << endl;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cQuery);
```

The output of both `cout` are:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=default
grant_type=client_credentials&scope=default
```

If I am using the `cQuery` variable as the value, the server is responding that i didnt specify the grant type.

If I am replacing

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cQuery);`

with

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=default");`

it works fine.

My background is more Java and C# related, so i am assuming i missunderstand some of the c++ basics. I am also a newbie on stackoverflow, so if i am doing sth. wrong please let me know.

I am looking forward to your answers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html - read the second paragraph of the description very closely, you probably have lifetume issues, but the code you provided isn't complete enough to be certain.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mat, it worked like a charme. I will add the solution to the question and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mat 's comment i got the solution:

I replaced

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cQuery);`

with

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(cQuery));`

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, cQuery);`